# SQL Sum and Groupby Statement return wrong/weird number

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's get to the point:

My first query:

```
select hotel, sum(adult) from bookings 
group by hotel;
```

and it shows the correct sum number, but whenever I try to join with other table:

```
select  b.hotel,    avg(r.hotelfacilities) as FacilitiesScore, 
                    avg(r.hotelservice) as ServiceScore, 
                    avg(r.hotelroom) as RoomScore, 
                    avg(b.rate) as PriceScore, 
                    sum(b.adult) as Persons
from bookings b join reviews r
on b.id = r.booking_id
group by b.hotel;
```

the number is weird and a lot bigger than it should be. Where did I do wrong?

Comment: GROUP BY in a subqueries before joining,.

Comment: The join will duplicate the booking row for each matching review. This explains why `avg(r.x)` works but `sum(b.x)` is multiplied.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  b.hotel,    
avg(r.hotelfacilities) as FacilitiesScore, 
avg(r.hotelservice) as ServiceScore, 
avg(r.hotelroom) as RoomScore, 
avg(b.rate) as PriceScore, 
sum(b.adult) as Persons
from bookings b join reviews r
group by b.hotel
on b.id = r.booking_id;
```

Comment: doesn't work. for some reason

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.